# How to intall Oracle JDK 32bit on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit along side the 64bit oracle jdk

Tags: 12.04, android, eclipse, jdk, oracle

I'm trying to transfer to 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 from 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04.

ADT for eclipse and the Android SDK requires 32bit Java but I would like to keep the 64 bit Java that I just got installed to run with NetBeans. Is there any way to install the two side by side using apt-get or will I have to manually install the 32 bit JDK?

this is the script i am trying to use to set the path to the 32 bit JDK:

```
#!/bin/bash


#Set version JDK 32

JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_25-i586
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
```

this is the result of running it:

[image]

so i manually entered each command from the script then started eclipse and got this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/opt/jdk1.7.0_25-i586/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library             /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.dist/eclipse_1408.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 24e8077
-vm /opt/jdk1.7.0_25-i586/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would recommend using the the JDK tar.gz packages (x86 and x64) from OTN and extract it to a preferred directory, using a quick shell script to switch JDK versions, e.g.

java.sh

```
#Set JDK versions
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_25
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
```

Another popular way to install JDK (kind of automated but a bit time consuming)

The most popular way NOW is: https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6

> NOTE: it builds .deb from OTN binaries and set up a local repository, install from there.

You can run `update-alternatives --config java` and see installed JDK/JRE and configure.

**To be able to use 32-bit JDK on 64-bit Linux**

You need to install the 32-bit shared libs (now Ubuntu uses something called [Multi-arch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch)).

If you don't have `ia32-libs` installed, you'll get File NOT FOUND error when running 32-bit java.

```
terry@tux:/opt/jdk1.7.0_25-i586/bin$ file java
java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, BuildID[sha1]=0xb4f81805640a786538c721d745f97f3485d03e3c, not stripped
terry@tux:/opt/jdk1.7.0_25-i586/bin$ ./java
bash: ./java: No such file or directory
```

That's probably why the shell script didn't work.

> NOTE: the script did do its job, see `which` output

```
terry@tux:/opt$ source java32.sh 
terry@tux:/opt$ which java
/opt/jdk1.7.0_25-i586/bin/java
```

Comment: so i would have two scripts and run one or the other depending on which jdk i want to use?

Comment: You don't have to. You can set the preferred JDK, .e.g. 64-bit in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` and the other using a script.

Comment: still getting the same error in eclipse

Comment: how can i tell if the path is set correctly after the script

Comment: 1. `echo $PATH` 2. `which java`

Comment: i will post the bash script, but it is basically the same as yours

Comment: when i run the script there appears to be no change in the my PATH or which version of java it seems to be pointing to

Comment: i have posted the results to your answer, doesnt appear to do anything, but i would be interested in a bash script that works in such a way

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: if you look in the photo the which output is /usr/bin/java after running the script, also ia32-libs is already the newest version

Comment: so i manually entered the each command from the bash script and got the error i posted above from eclipse

Comment: i did see source command, i will try

Comment: Eclispe has 32-bit and 64-bit, keep this in mind. Not sure how they work, I normally use 64-bit JDK with 64-bit Eclipse if I have to deal with Java LoL

Comment: well i have tried this on ubuntu 64 bit in these combinations: jdk-64 / eclipse 64/ sdk 64 , jdk-32 / eclipse 64/ sdk 64 ,jdk-32 / eclipse 32/ sdk 64 , jdk-32 / eclipse 32/ sdk 32 , and have not got any of the above, i am thinking of just installing 32 bit on my new system, i have android all set up on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit and it works just fine, its a 64 bit system too, an in to similar trouble on it and did the 32 bit thing sooner, but i really wanted 64 bit this time..