# install JRE 1.6 on 1.5 JDK

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I have Oracle JDK and JRE 1.5 installed  ubuntu LTS. I want to keep JDK 1.5 and install Oracle JRE as 1.6. please let me know the steps or any clear source where I can get this done

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to this question, should be helpful: [How to intall Oracle JDK 32bit on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit along side the 64bit oracle jdk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325103/how-to-intall-oracle-jdk-32bit-on-ubuntu-12-04-64bit-along-side-the-64bit-oracle/)

You can use the same script (or `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`) to set JRE/JDK you want. For browsers, you can create symbolic link in `~/.mozilla/plugins` to JRE 1.6 (e.g. `/path/to/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`) so that Firefox, Chrome, Chromium uses 1.6 instead of 1.5.

BTW: I would recommend using Java SE 7, no point to use 6.